# Toggle opacity animation on nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, opacity

Objective: give opacity to nav bar when to reach a certain position on the scroll.
so far it works on load but when scrolling back up opacity doesn't go back to 0.

```
 function navanim() {
  var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
  var div_top = $('#news').offset().top;
  if (window_top > 500)

      $('.nav').animate({
          'opacity': '1'
      }, 500);
  else 

      $('.nav').css("opacity", 0);

  }
  $(function() {
  $(window).scroll(navanim);
  navanim();

  });
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle example...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=bNrSRViwmB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having played around with a your code, it appears the problem may be related to animate, css and potentially other methods being called too often (on every scroll).

I have reimplemented a small example based on your ideas:

[Simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/mattsturgeon/5myeubhm/)

The above jsfiddle uses the following function to check if an animation is necessary by keeping track of the state, and if so do that animation.

```
var navAnimation = (function() {
    var news = $('#news'),
      header = $('header'),
      winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      newsTop = news.offset().top,
      show = winTop < newsTop;

    return function navAnimation () { 
      winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      newsTop = news.offset().top;

      // Don't run uneccissarily
      if (show && winTop < newsTop) return;
      if (!show && winTop >= newsTop) return;

      // If something changed, update our state
      show = winTop < newsTop;

      if (show) {
        console.log('animate!');
        header.animate({
          opacity: 1
        }, 500);
      } else {
        header.animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 500);
      }
    };
})();

$( document ).ready(function(){
  $( window ).scroll(navAnimation);
  navAnimation();
});
```

Comment: @KhalilLajmi no problem, if my answer helped you It'd be great if you marked it as accepted